# Select * group by in oracle

Tags: oracle

How would I write this simple mysql equivalent in oracle?

```
select * from table group by column
```

It seems it does not accept star char when groupping, but it's really not practical to select columns one by one when there are 30+ columns in table.

Comment: It seems you want to use `order by`.

Comment: Because this kind of grouping makes no sense at all.

Comment: Every expression in the `select` clause must either be a literal value, an aggregation or also appear in the `group by` clause.

Comment: @ammoQ how does that makes no sense? I have some rows with identical values except one column about which I don't care so I use group by to get only one of each duplicity

Comment: What would be the output for the one column with different values? Whatever the database finds first? Oracle doesn't work like that, most of the times the results are *predictable*.

Comment: Ok so oracle is strictly deterministic. Ok I get it now, thanks @ammoQ

Comment: Not strictly; for example, without an `order by` clause, the order of the resulting rows is unpredictable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from table
WHERE rowid in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
FROM table
GROUP BY column);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the column names explicitly for which you want to group. So, your SQL in Oracle would be :

```
select column_list from table group by column_list
```

or,

```
select few/any columns from table group by same columns + more columns
```

Also, remember the column_list in select must be at least present in group by clause in the same order. You can select fewer columns and still group by those columns and additionally other columns too.

For example,

```
select ename from emp group by ename,sal
```

Comment: I just realized that my answer has been voted down after it was voted up once, as an etiquette, may I please know the reason whoever voted down. As I or others would never come to know the reason, as well as, the help that is further required.

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but I can say why I didn't vote it up: your query is not the equivalent of mentioned mysql query, as it doesn't list all columns. If oracle's group by don't allow this, there has to be different way to produce same output as mysql returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same behaviour as in e.g. MySQL, you need to use an aggregate function, something like the MAX or MIN functions in oracle. Unfortunately, the only way I know to get the entire row back (rather than random field values from different rows) is to concatenate values together:

```
SELECT
    col_to_group_by,
    MAX(col_1 || ', ' || col_2 || ', ' || col_3 || ', ' || col_4) row_values
FROM table_name
GROUP BY col_to_group_by
```